# How to install same app with 2 different product flavors?

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have this app with a package name `corp.acme.app` and 2 product flavors called `apple` and `pears`. Their build files are shown with brevity below.

**1. Module-level build file**

```
// project-path/project_app/build.gradle

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId('corp.acme.app')
    }
    flavorDimensions "crunchy"
    productFlavors {
        apple {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".apple"
            dimension "crunchy"
        }
        pears {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".pears"
            dimension "crunchy"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**2. Apple product flavor JSON file**

```
// project-path/project_app/src/apple/google-services.json

{
    ...
    "client": [{
        "client_info": {
            "mobilesdk_app_id": "gibberish:android:gibberish",
            "android_client_info": {
            "package_name": "corp.acme.app.apple"
            }
        },
        ...
    }]
}
```

**3. Pears product flavor JSON file**

```
// project-path/project_app/src/pears/google-services.json

{
    ...
    "client": [{
        "client_info": {
            "mobilesdk_app_id": "gibberish:android:gibberish",
            "android_client_info": {
            "package_name": "corp.acme.app.pears"
            }
        },
        ...
    }]
}
```

I was able to successfully generate signed APKs for both. The problem though is they are not able to be installed both at the same time. One has to be uninstalled before installing the other.

Did I miss something? How to install same app with 2 different product flavors?

Comment: use different appId `corp.acme.app`

Comment: To the one who downvoted, please state the reason so I could improve the question/post.

Comment: @Kasnady when you say *appId*, did you mean `applicationId` ?

Comment: Weird; your setup looks ok to me. What is the actual error you get when attempting to install a second flavor on the same device? Or does it just overwrite the already-installed flavor?

Comment: When I try to install the second one, it would simply say "App not installed." That's just it. It also doesn't overwrite the already-installed flavor.

Comment: I don't think it's even possible with same package name.

Comment: Do you see anything more than "App not installed" in the logcat output? There's usually more detail there.

Comment: From what you showed in your question, everything looks good.

Are both variants signed with the same key?

Do you have in your manifest any permission with protection level signature?

If the variants are signed with different keys and you have in the manifest some custom permission with signature protection level you won't be able to install both applications in the same device even though they have different application IDs.

This is just a guess since you didn't give enough information to validate this.

From the info you provide everything looks good.

Comment: Hello @AbelCallejo have You fixed this issue? currently I am facing same issue which you were facing to while installing application....Please suggest me so that I can solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In module build.gradle file

```
flavorDimensions "crunchy"
            productFlavors {
                apple {
                    applicationId 'corp.acme.app.apple'
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.AppleConfig
                    dimension "crunchy"
                }
                pears {
                    applicationId 'corp.acme.app.pears'
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.PearsConfig
                    dimension "crunchy"
                }
            }
```

when running project change build variants to respective flavor

```
In src folder 
-create apple and pears folder 
Package structure like
    -src 
        -apple
            -google-services.json
        -pears
            -google-services.json
        -main
```

Answer (score 0):

Make each of the flavor to have different `applicationId` in your `build.gradle`

Comment: Why downgrade, I was faster

Comment: Disclaimer: that was not me. Anyways, going back to the topic. Both flavors already have different `applicationIdSuffix`-es. Is it not enough? Should I use `applicationId` instead of `applicationIdSuffix` ?

Comment: I haven't used applicationSuffix but applicationId works for me

Answer (score 0):

Update the below code in you gradle

```
 android {
     flavorDimensions "fav1"
            productFlavors {
                fav1 {
                    applicationId "com.fav1.android"
                    //optional if you want to set some data based on fav type
                    buildConfigField 'String', 'server_url', '"http://serverurl.com"'
                    resValue 'string', 'access_key', 'sdgsdfgsgsdg'
                    resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'App Name Fav1'
                }

                fav2 {
                    applicationId "com.fav2.android"
                    //optional if you want to set some data based on fav type
                    buildConfigField 'String', 'server_url', '"http://serverurl1.com"'
                    resValue 'string', 'access_key', 'dfssdfsdf'
                    resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'App Name Fav2'
                }
            }
    }
```

How to access buildConfigField  and res value

**buildConfigField**

```
 String serverUrl=BuildConfig.server_url;
```

**res value**

```
   <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/access_key" />
```

OR

```
String key=getString(R.String.key)
```

**AppName**

```
 <application
              android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Some time Flavors build need different value for different Flavors ,for example

- if need to change Application Name based on Flavors  build
- Need to base URL of server
- Facebook id so we can

specify such information from gradle.

Comment: What is the purpose for having `buildConfigField`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different `applicationId` in `build.gradle` file.

EDIT:

**Remove `applicationId` from `defaultConfig`:**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId('corp.acme.app') <-- Remove this line
}
```

**Add `applicationId` to `productFlavors` and remove `applicationIdSuffix` :**

```
    productFlavors {
        apple {
            applicationId "corp.acme.app.apple" <-- Add this line
            dimension "crunchy"
        }
        pears {
            applicationId "corp.acme.app.pears" <-- Add this line
            dimension "crunchy"
        }
    }
```

Comment: in this case, how should I go about it?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I see, I'm gonna try that now.

Answer (score -1):

I think your `applicationIdSuffix` is not working properly please read bellow tow line from official android flavour document.

**Caution:** For compatibility with previous SDK tools, if you do not define the applicationId property in your build.gradle file, the build tools use the package name from the AndroidManifest.xml file as the application ID. In that case, refactoring your package name also changes your application ID.

**Tip:** If you need to reference the application ID in your manifest file, you can use the `${applicationId}` placeholder in any manifest attribute. During a build, Gradle replaces this tag with the actual application ID. For more information, see Inject Build Variables into the Manifest.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html

Comment: The `applicationId` _is_ defined though.

Comment: Okay, Then it may be some different issue.